# SetAttribute any way to add more than 1 string c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add more than 1 string to this line of code

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("test").SetAttribute("value", classes.Class1.RandomPassword.Generate(5, 10));
```

What I want to do is after `RandomPassword.Generate(5, 10)` happens I want to add extra text that I can put text in so for example it would look like this

```
dg#"%rgdf then my text here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the + sign like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("test").SetAttribute("value", classes.Class1.RandomPassword.Generate(5, 10) + "MY TEXT");
```

Comment: Since that was helpful you can upvote and accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable to store something in it momentarily:

```
var passAndText = classes.Class1.RandomPassword.Generate(5, 10);
passAndText = passAndText + "whatever";
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("test").SetAttribute("value", passAndText);
```